# Minimization problem

Tags: equation-solving

How could you find the smallest constant $c$ that satisfies

$$\frac{3^{3k}e\sqrt{3}}{\pi\sqrt{k}\;2^{3/2+2k}} \leq 2^{\;c\;k}$$

assuming $k\geq 1$ is an integer.

You can of course take logs of both sides and divide by $k$.
Can *Mathematica* then somehow minimize for $c$?

The code for the main term above is

```
(E/Sqrt[2Pi])/(x^(n x) (1 - x)^(n (1 - x)) Sqrt[ 2Pi n x (1 - x)])/. x -> 1/3 /. n->3k
```

Comment: Could you please post _Mathematica_ code ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks Done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Going with your suggestion to take the `Log` of both sides we, after simplification, end up with:

```
(2 + k Log[729/16] + Log[3/(8 k π^2)])/(k Log[4]) <= c
```

Noticing that the lhs is strictly increasing in the domain of interest:

```
f[k_] := (2 + k Log[729/16] + Log[3/(8 k π^2)])/(k Log[4])

Reduce[ k >= 1 && f'[k] > 0, k]
(* k >= 1 *)
```

We can just take the limit as $k \rightarrow \infty$ to get the global suprema, which will also be the minima for `c`:

```
Limit[ f[k], k->Infinity]
(* Log[729/16]/Log[4] *)
```

**Edit** Old answer below:

Not a full answer, but perhaps helpful anyway.

For fixed `k` [`Minimize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Minimize.html) is able to find the minimal `c` when putting the inequality as a constraint:

```
cmin[k_Integer] := cmin[k] = Block[{c},
  ArgMin[{ c, (3^(3 k) E Sqrt[3])/(π Sqrt[k] 2^(3/2 + 2 k)) <= 2^(c k)}, c]]

cmin[200]
(* (2 - 806 Log[2] + 1201 Log[3] - 2 Log[5] - 2 Log[π])/(400 Log[2]) *)

DiscretePlot[ cmin[k], {k, 1, 200}, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: minplot]

Comment: That is a nice solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I want to add that *Mathematica* isn't needed for this task.

You can see than the *lhs* behaves like $(3^3/2^2)^k$. The *rhs* is $2^{ck}$. Therefore
$$
c = 3\log_23-2.
$$

Also you can easily proof than the ratio *lhs/rhs* monotonically increases for $k\ge1$.

Answer (score 4):

It can also be solved directly by setting the two sides equal:

```
sol = Solve[(3^(3 k) E Sqrt[3])/(π Sqrt[k] 2^(3/2 + 2 k)) == 2^(c k), c, Reals]
```

which gives an expression for `c` in terms of `k` as long as `k > 0`.

```
{{c -> ConditionalExpression[(2 - 3 Log[2] - 4 k Log[2] + Log[3] + 6 k Log[3] + 
        2 Log[1/(Sqrt[k] π)])/(2 k Log[2]), k > 0]}}
```

Set this equal to a function

```
    f[k_] := sol[[1, 1, 2, 1]]
```

and find the limit as `k -> Infinity`:

```
Limit[ f[k], k -> Infinity]
```

which is

```
   Log[27/4]/Log[2]
```

Comment: I am looking for a constant value of $c$ that holds for all integer $k \geq 1$.

Comment: Could you explain the code sol[[1, 1, 2, 1]] please ? That is new to me.

Comment: @felix If you evaluate `sol` then `sol[[1]]` then `sol[[1,1]]` then .... you'll see what's going on. [relevant documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PartsOfExpressions.html)

Comment: This is picking out the function of `k` from the `ConditionalExpression` (it is the 1,1,2,1 element of the list defined by `sol`). It might be more straightforward to copy/paste the function into `f[ ]`, but this was quicker to type.